# Restarting IIS6 - Python

Tags: python, windows, django, iis, iis-6

I'm serving a **Django app** behind **IIS 6**. I'm wondering if I can **restart** IIS 6 within Python/Django and what one of the best ways to do would be.

Help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides what's already suggested, you can also use  [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) via either the [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394418) or the [IIsWebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525249(v=VS.90).aspx) class, which inherits from it. There is a Python WMI [wrapper](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/) available, which is based on [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

**UPDATE:** A quick test of the following worked for me.

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()

for service in c.Win32_Service(Name="W3SVC"):
    result, = service.StopService()
```

I didn't test the next piece of code, but something like this should also work:

```
for service in c.IIsWebService():
    result, = service.StopService()
```

You can see the documentation for the return values from the [StopService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393673) and [StartService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393660) methods.

Comment: that looks like it might be very useful for me! Thank you very much! I cannot figure out a way to restart IIS though :(

Answer (score 1):

The following post shows how to control Windows services from Python: http://fuzzytolerance.info/code/using-python-to-manage-windows-services/

You should be able that to restart the IIS web publishing service (known as 'w3svc')

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can execute an iisreset via a commandline. I've never tried that with Django but it should work and be quite simple to implement.